# SQL Timeout and Query Performance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP(100)
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG_RAUM.RAUMID,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG.VON,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG.BIS,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG.RAUMBEZEICHNUNG,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG.THEMA,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG.V_EMAIL,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG.VERANSTALTER,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG_RAUM.COLOR,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG.RAUMID AS Expr1,
    VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG_RAUM.BEZEICHNUNG
FROM VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG
RIGHT OUTER JOIN VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG_RAUM ON VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG.RAUMID = VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG_RAUM.RAUMID
```

Is there a way to improve this? VIEW_RAUMBUCHUNG contains 27000 entries, and the performance is very slow, even if I limit results to the first 100 records. Or is there a way to optimize the SQL-Server?

My second problem is, if i try to load the whole 27000 entries, I get a timeout after 20 seconds, but I set the timeout in IIS to 120 seconds. Why is that and how can I avoid a timeout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TOP 100` with no `ORDER BY`? Do you want random results?

Comment: In the grand scheme of data volume, 27000 records is statistically indistinguishable from 0 records.  The number of records isn't the problem.  Also, what does a timeout in IIS have to do with your database?  Is it even the database query that's taking a long time, or is the bottleneck somewhere else in the technology stack?  First, identify your actual bottleneck.   If it's in the database query, then run the query through an analyzer to look at the execution plan.  It should indicate any table scans or excessive data manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create **Indexes** on the RaumID fields in the two tables
2. Create a **view** instead of joining the two tables
3. Set your **timeout** to a larger values or to 0 which means it won't timeout

Comment: how can i create an index on the two tables and how can i set that timeout?

Comment: @Paks, on how to create an index, here is all the info you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189271(v=sql.105)  Be sure to select the SQL version you are using on top of page

Comment: You can set the timeout by opening the server in sql server management studio, right click the server, go to properties, go to the connections page and look for a sql query timeout setting.